# Angular : getList() function Called Twice After Navigating to a Different Page and Resetting Query

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented pagination and filtering functionality. The problem arises when I navigate to a different page using the toPage() function and then press the reset button, triggering the resetQuery() function. In this specific scenario, the getList() function is being called twice. However, if I change some filters and then clear/reset the query, it is called only once. I am trying to understand the reason behind this behavior and how to resolve it.

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect that the getList() function should be called once after navigating to a different page and resetting the query, similar to the behavior observed when changing filters and then clearing the query.

1. Why is the getList() function being called twice after navigating to
   a different page and resetting the query, while it is called only
   once after changing filters and clearing the query?
2. What could be the possible reasons behind this behavior, and how can I ensure that
   getList() is called only once in all scenarios?

```
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    imports: [PaginationModule, RouterModule, SharedModule],
    //....
})
export class OrderHistoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public list = { total: 0, value: [] };
    public rows = 5;
    public page = 1;
    public isListLoading = true;
    public emptyQuery = {
        name: '',
        username: '',
        email: '',
        rows: this.rows,
        page: this.page,
        address: '',
        sort: 'SalesId',
        order: 'asc',
    };
    public query = structuredClone(this.emptyQuery);
    private debounceSubject = new Subject();

    constructor(
        private readonly router: Router,
        private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
       //..services
    ) {}

    async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        this.updateQueryFromUrl();
        await this.loadData();
        this.setupDebouncing();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.debounceSubject.unsubscribe();
    }

    async getList() {
        this.loaderService.show();
        this.isListLoading = true;
        //getting the data async
        } catch (error) {
            // handle errors
        } finally {
            this.isListLoading = false;
        }
    }

    toPage(page) {
        this.query.page = page.page;
        this.router.navigate([], {
            relativeTo: this.route,
            queryParams: this.getNonEmptyQueryParams(),
            queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
        });
        this.getList();
    }

    onFilterChange() {
        this.query.page = 1;
        this.debounceSubject.next();
    }

    updateQueryFromUrl() {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
            if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
                Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
                    if (key == 'page' || key == 'rows') {
                        this.query[key] = parseInt(params[key]);
                        return;
                    }
                    this.query[key] = params[key];
                });
            }
        });
    }

    resetQuery() {
        this.query = structuredClone(this.emptyQuery);
        this.router.navigate([], {
            relativeTo: this.route,
            queryParams: this.getNonEmptyQueryParams(),
            queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
        });
        this.getList();
    }

    handleSort(key) {
        if (!key) return;
        this.query.page = 1;
        this.query.sort = key;
        this.query.order = this.query.order == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        const queryParams = this.getNonEmptyQueryParams();
        this.router.navigate([], {
            relativeTo: this.route,
            queryParams: queryParams,
            queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
        });
        this.getList();
    }

    getNonEmptyQueryParams() {
        const queryParam = {};
        Object.keys(this.query).forEach((key) => {
            if (this.query[key]) {
                queryParam[key] = this.query[key];
            }
        });
        return queryParam;
    }

    private setupDebouncing(): void {
        this.debounceSubject.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(() => {
            this.router.navigate([], {
                relativeTo: this.route,
                queryParams: this.getNonEmptyQueryParams(),
                queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
            });
            this.getList();
        });
    }
```